# R: NaN came up after as.numeric() while using dplyr sparklyr / maniplating data with pipes in sparklyr connection

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, nan, sparklyr

I began to use sparklyr to handle big size data, so I need to use only pipe lines.

But while manupulating data frame I got in trouble and it seems by

```
csj %>% head()
```

below is how my data looks like. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1ESp.png)

What I want to do is first, I want to make a new column, lenght_of_review, with counting number of characters of reviewText and another new column which can show categories.

So I put code like this:

```
csj<- csj %>% mutate(length_of_review = nchar(csj$reviewText,keppNA=TRUE),
                     category ="Clothes_shoes_jewelry") %>% 
              select(c('_c0',reviewerID,asin,helpful,length_of_review,overall,unixReviewTime,category))

csj %>% head()
Error: Invalid number of args to SQL LENGTH. Expecting 1
```

Category part worked but length_of_review part didn't work. So I tired with as.numeric again

```
csj<- csj %>% mutate(length_of_review = as.numeric(nchar(csj$reviewText)),
                     category ="Clothes_shoes_jewelry") %>% 
              select(c('_c0',reviewerID,asin,helpful,length_of_review,overall,unixReviewTime,category))

csj %>% head()
#Source:   lazy query [?? x 8]
# Database: spark_connection
  `_c0` reviewerID     asin  helpful length_of_review overall unixReviewTime category             
  <int> <chr>          <chr> <chr>              <dbl> <chr>   <chr>          <chr>                
1     0 A1KLRMWW2FWPL4 31887 [0, 0]               NaN 5       1297468800     Clothes_shoes_jewelry
2     1 A2G5TCU2WDFZ65 31887 [0, 0]               NaN 5       1358553600     Clothes_shoes_jewelry
3     2 A1RLQXYNCMWRWN 31887 [0, 0]               NaN 5       1357257600     Clothes_shoes_jewelry
4     3 A8U3FAMSJVHS5  31887 [0, 0]               NaN 5       1398556800     Clothes_shoes_jewelry
5     4 A3GEOILWLK86XM 31887 [0, 0]               NaN 5       1394841600     Clothes_shoes_jewelry
6     5 A27UF1MSF3DB2  31887 [0, 0]               NaN 4       1396224000     Clothes_shoes_jewelry
```

And it turns to NAN :(.....

Also, simiar but another problem is about helpful coulmn.
I want to make a new column called as help = first # in helpful / 2nd # in helpful. I asked in here site before and I got this code:

```
csj %>%
+   mutate(col1 = as.numeric(stringi::stri_extract_first_regex(csj$helpful, pattern = "[0-9]")),#extract first number
+          col2 = as.numeric(stringi::stri_extract_last_regex(csj$helpful, pattern = "[0-9]")),#extract second
+          col3 = ifelse(col2 == 0, 1, col2 ),#change 0s to 1
+          help = col1/col3) #divide row1 and 3


# Source:   lazy query [?? x 12]
# Database: spark_connection
   `_c0` reviewerID     asin  helpful length_of_review overall unixReviewTime category     col1  col2  col3  help
   <int> <chr>          <chr> <chr>              <dbl> <chr>   <chr>          <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0 A1KLRMWW2FWPL4 31887 [0, 0]               NaN 5       1297468800     Clothes_sh~   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 2     1 A2G5TCU2WDFZ65 31887 [0, 0]               NaN 5       1358553600     Clothes_sh~   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 3     2 A1RLQXYNCMWRWN 31887 [0, 0]               NaN 5       1357257600     Clothes_sh~   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 4     3 A8U3FAMSJVHS5  31887 [0, 0]               NaN 5       1398556800     Clothes_sh~   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 5     4 A3GEOILWLK86XM 31887 [0, 0]               NaN 5       1394841600     Clothes_sh~   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 6     5 A27UF1MSF3DB2  31887 [0, 0]               NaN 4       1396224000     Clothes_sh~   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 7     6 A16GFPNVF4Y816 31887 [0, 0]               NaN 5       1399075200     Clothes_sh~   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 8     7 A2M2APVYIB2U6K 31887 [0, 0]               NaN 5       1356220800     Clothes_sh~   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 9     8 A1NJ71X3YPQNQ9 31887 [0, 0]               NaN 4       1384041600     Clothes_sh~   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
10     9 A3EERSWHAI6SO  31887 [7, 8]               NaN 5       1349568000     Clothes_sh~   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
# ... with more rows
```

Both problems seems should work, but it didn't work. I couldn't even start analysis because I'm stuck here such a long time :(

Is there anyone knows why? and has a solution for this? I'll be very much happy if I can solve these problems. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is str(csj) >>

```
    > str(csj)
List of 2
 $ src:List of 1
  ..$ con:List of 10
  .. ..$ master       : chr "local[4]"
  .. ..$ method       : chr "shell"
  .. ..$ app_name     : chr "sparklyr"
  .. ..$ config       :List of 4
  .. .. ..$ spark.env.SPARK_LOCAL_IP.local    : chr "127.0.0.1"
  .. .. ..$ sparklyr.csv.embedded             : chr "^1.*"
  .. .. ..$ sparklyr.cores.local              : int 4
  .. .. ..$ spark.sql.shuffle.partitions.local: int 4
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "config")= chr "default"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "file")= chr "C:\\Users\\ms\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\3.5\\sparklyr\\conf\\config-template.yml"
  .. ..$ spark_home   : chr "C:\\spark"
  .. ..$ backend      : 'sockconn' int 4
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "conn_id")=<externalptr> 
  .. ..$ monitor      : 'sockconn' int 3
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "conn_id")=<externalptr> 
  .. ..$ output_file  : chr "C:\\Users\\ms\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpygTIca\\file371068ce6a02_spark.log"
  .. ..$ spark_context:Classes 'spark_jobj', 'shell_jobj' <environment: 0x00000000daa77a50> 
  .. ..$ java_context :Classes 'spark_jobj', 'shell_jobj' <environment: 0x00000000daa365b8> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "spark_connection" "spark_shell_connection" "DBIConnection"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "src_spark" "src_sql" "src"
 $ ops:List of 4
  ..$ name: chr "select"
  ..$ x   :List of 4
  .. ..$ name: chr "mutate"
  .. ..$ x   :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ x   : 'ident' chr "review_csj"
  .. .. ..$ vars: chr [1:7] "_c0" "reviewerID" "asin" "helpful" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "op_base_remote" "op_base" "op"
  .. ..$ dots:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ length_of_review: language ~as.numeric(nchar(NULL))
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x00000000dd5f2548> 
  .. .. ..$ category        : language ~"Clothes_shoes_jewelry"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_EmptyEnv> 
  .. ..$ args: list()
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "op_mutate" "op_single" "op"
  ..$ dots:List of 1
  .. ..$ : language ~c("_c0", reviewerID, asin, helpful, length_of_review, overall, unixReviewTime, category)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x00000000dd6190f0> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "quosures"
  ..$ args: list()
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "op_select" "op_single" "op"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:4] "tbl_spark" "tbl_sql" "tbl_lazy" "tbl"
>
```

Here is my session_info()

```
Session info ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.1.453)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       Europe/Berlin               
 date     2018-05-21                  

Packages --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package      * version date       source        
 assertthat     0.2.0   2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 backports      1.1.2   2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 base         * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 base64enc      0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 bindr          0.1.1   2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 bindrcpp       0.2.2   2018-03-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 broom          0.4.4   2018-03-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 cli            1.0.0   2017-11-05 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 colorspace     1.3-2   2016-12-14 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 compiler       3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 config         0.3     2018-03-27 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 crayon         1.3.4   2017-09-16 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 datasets     * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 DBI            1.0.0   2018-05-02 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 dbplyr         1.2.1   2018-02-19 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 devtools     * 1.13.5  2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 digest       * 0.6.15  2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 dplyr        * 0.7.5   2018-05-19 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 foreign        0.8-70  2017-11-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 ggplot2      * 2.2.1   2016-12-30 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 glue           1.2.0   2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 graphics     * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 grDevices    * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 grid         * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 gtable         0.2.0   2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 hms            0.4.2   2018-03-10 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 htmltools      0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 httpuv         1.4.3   2018-05-10 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 httr           1.3.1   2017-08-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 jsonlite       1.5     2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 later          0.7.2   2018-05-01 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 lattice        0.20-35 2017-03-25 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 lazyeval       0.2.1   2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 magrittr       1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 memoise        1.1.0   2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 methods      * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 mime           0.5     2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 mnormt         1.5-5   2016-10-15 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 munsell        0.4.3   2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 nlme           3.1-137 2018-04-07 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 openssl        1.0.1   2018-03-03 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 parallel       3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 pillar         1.2.2   2018-04-26 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 pkgconfig      2.0.1   2017-03-21 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 plyr           1.8.4   2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 promises       1.0.1   2018-04-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 psych          1.8.4   2018-05-06 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 purrr          0.2.4   2017-10-18 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 R6             2.2.2   2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 RColorBrewer * 1.1-2   2014-12-07 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 Rcpp           0.12.17 2018-05-18 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 readr        * 1.1.1   2017-05-16 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 reshape2       1.4.3   2017-12-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 rlang          0.2.0   2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 rprojroot      1.3-2   2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 rstudioapi     0.7     2017-09-07 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 scales       * 0.5.0   2017-08-24 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 shiny          1.1.0   2018-05-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 sparklyr     * 0.8.3   2018-05-12 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 stats        * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 stringi      * 1.1.7   2018-03-12 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 stringr      * 1.3.1   2018-05-10 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 tibble         1.4.2   2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 tidyr        * 0.8.1   2018-05-18 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 tidyselect     0.2.4   2018-02-26 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 tools          3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 utf8           1.1.3   2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 utils        * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 withr          2.1.2   2018-03-15 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 xtable         1.8-2   2016-02-05 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 yaml           2.1.19  2018-05-01 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've made two fundamental mistakes, where the former one actually masks the latter one. Let's trace it step-by-step.

```
df <- copy_to(
  sc, tibble(id=1, helpful="[0, 0]", reviewText="Here goes some text")
)
```

- The first mistake is attempt to use `$` to access columns. `tbl_spark` (and as far as I am aware other database-based objects, like `tbl_sql`) objects don't provide `$` access:

  ```
  > df$a
  NULL
  ```

  and in general you shouldn't reference columns like this with `dplyr`.
- `sparklyr` doesn't support direct execution of plain R code (with exception of functions like `spark_apply`. These are however very inefficient).

  So if you omit `$` query would actually fail:

  ```
  > df %>% mutate(length_of_review = nchar(reviewText, keppNA=TRUE))
  Error: Invalid number of args to SQL LENGTH. Expecting 1
  ```

  You could omit R specific arguments:

  ```
  > df %>% mutate(length_of_review = nchar(reviewText))
  # Source:   lazy query [?? x 4]
  # Database: spark_connection
       id helpful reviewText          length_of_review
    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>                          <int>
  1     1 [0, 0]  Here goes some text               19
  ```

  which would be translated to a native Spark call of `length` function (note that it is not `base::length`):

  ```
  > df %>% mutate(length_of_review = length(reviewText))
  # Source:   lazy query [?? x 4]
  # Database: spark_connection
       id helpful reviewText          length_of_review
    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>                          <int>
  1     1 [0, 0]  Here goes some text               19
  ```

In general operations applied on connection will be [translated to SQL queries](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/sql-translation.html) so you should use functions, which are accessible on a specific platform (or are aliased by `dplyr`). For the list of available functions, with their arguments you can check [the official Scala documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$).

Regarding your problems:

- To check length use `length` function (see above).
- To process strings with regular expressions use `regexp_extract` function with *Java regular expressions*:

  ```
  > df %>% mutate(col1 = as.numeric(regexp_extract(helpful, "^\\\\[([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)\\\\]$", 1)))
  # Source:   lazy query [?? x 4]
  # Database: spark_connection
       id helpful reviewText           col1
    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>               <dbl>
  1     1 [0, 0]  Here goes some text     0
  ```

  You could also use [`spark_apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6910411+spark_apply), but as already mentioned, it is not an efficient approach.